# Change image according to value of MaterialUI slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to use a [discrete Slider component from Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#discrete-sliders) to change a picture in a React web app: every time the user changes the value on the slider, a different picture should be displayed in a specified div.
How can I do it? I guess that this starts with invoking a handleChange function in onChange within the Slider component, but how could I move forward?

```js
const {Slider, Typography} =  MaterialUI

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([20, 30])
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
  }
  return (
    <form>

      <Slider
        defaultValue={30}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        step={10}
        marks
        min={10}
        max={100}
      />
      
      <Typography>state value: {JSON.stringify(value)} </Typography>

    </form>
  )
}
    
    
// boilerplate to init the app    
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('main'))
```

```css
#main { margin-top: 15% }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

<main id="main"></main>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at this [nearby example](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#slider-with-input-field) to see how to tie two things together. Instead of using a `defaultValue`, you would use just `value` and the default gets set when you initialize the state (you have it as an array, it should be just a number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to listen to slider events like `onChangeCommitted={handleChange}`.

**NL;PR:** I modified your code with a slider changing the URL text on slide events [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-o2556). You have to make your Slider controlled (the state is managed externally: `const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);`). Now you provide the current value `value={value}` and decide when to update it like when the user interacts with it `onChange={handleChange}` (any slide change) or `onChangeCommitted={handleChange}` (only the last change after the user let go of the slider). Finally, you can obtain the user selection from `newValue` as you already set in this callback: `const handleChange = (event, newValue) => { setValue(newValue); };`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a option to combine image and slider in one component ist is very simple:

create an array of image paths and show only the image from the path at the slider position

```
<image src{paths[value]} />
```

Otherwise you need to save the slider value in a component both child components can access or use something like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)